# How get only one item with 'limit' in a list in sugar

Tags: android, sugarorm

I'm using sugar with Android to try to get only one result of my list

This is the query that I'm trying...

String myName= "Steve"

```
List<MyClass> existingHniNetwork = MyClass.find(MyClass.class, "name=?", myName, null, null, "1");
```

This is the example that I get from the oficial documentation, but not sure if I'm applied well:

```
find(Class<T> type, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs, String groupBy, String orderBy, String limit)
```

My query don't find any result, but if I do this, I can get a list but I only one one result of this list:

```
List<MyClass> existingHniNetwork = MyClass.find(MyClass.class, "name=?", myName);
```

Comment: Yes, only one result, Imagine that I have a list of 4 people with the same name, I only want to get one of them, maybe the first. For this, I'm trying to use limit 1, to get only one result if match the query

Comment: Basically, that I want is do one query of this two: List<Author> authors = Author.find(Author.class, "full_name = ?", "Nathan");
List<Book> books = Book.findWithQuery(Book.class, "Select * from Book limit ?", "4"); can find by author and limit the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, `find` method requires an array of String for the `whereArgs`, you can try this and see if it works for you:

```
List<MyClass> existingHniNetwork = MyClass.find(MyClass.class, "name=?", new String[]{myName}, null, null, "1");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code**

```
List<MyClass> existingHniNetwork = MyClass.find(MyClass.class, "name=?", new String[]{myName}, null, null, "1");
```

Here is the method signature for **find()**

```
find(Class<T> type, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs, String groupBy, String orderBy, String limit)
```

**Documentation link:** http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html